# Merging vector layers via python in QGIS 2.18.1

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I am currently using the following code to merge two vector layers together:

```
def append_layers(layer1, layer2, output):
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
    Processing.initialize()
    import processing.tools
    processing.tools.general.runalg("qgis:mergevectorlayers", layer1, layer2, output)

append_layers(layer1.shp, layer2.shp, output.shp)
```

This seems to work fine in QGIS 2.14, however it fails in 2.18.1 with the following message:

```
Error: Wrong number of parameters
ALGORITHM: Merge vector layers
```

Is there something that has changed between 2.14 and 2.18? Or am i just missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, if you type in the following code in the **Python Console**, the input layer parameter now incorporates **multiple layers**:

```
>>>import processing
>>>processing.alghelp("qgis:mergevectorlayers")
ALGORITHM: Merge vector layers
    LAYERS <ParameterMultipleInput>
    OUTPUT <OutputVector>
```

---

So one way of resolving this is to add both layers into the input parameter and split them:

```
processing.tools.general.runalg("qgis:mergevectorlayers", layer1 + ";" + layer2, output)
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked fine.

Has the procedure for 
    'runalg("gdalogr:convertformat")'

changed too? On 2.14 it works using 
    'processing.tools.general.runalg('gdalogr:convertformat', layer, filetype, "", save_location)'

but on 2.18 no errors are flagged up but new files are not created.

Comment: @JamieTasker - Most welcome! Nope, should be the same parameters. Just tested it and it works fine. If you have problems, you should [ask a new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and include all the details such as the input layer type, the output layer type, your code etc :)

Comment: @Joseph I get the same error Jochen has described in his answer. I'm using version 2.18.16 Python console. It would be interesting to know since which version only a Python list works as vector layer input.

Comment: @Stefan - I believe the developers changed how the inputs should be used. In the early 2.18 version, layers needed to be separated by a semi-colon which was eventually changed to allow lists. There was a [post asking about this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251773/qgismergevectorlayers-wont-allow-two-layers-for-the-second-arg).

Answer (score 4):

Since trying above answer causes an exception (`l1` and `l2` are both of type `QgsVectorLayer`, QGIS 2.18.17 Python console) for me

```
import processing
[...]
processing.runalg('qgis:mergevectorlayers', l1 + ";" + l2, None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'QgsVectorLayer' and 'str'
```

I've been trying

```
>>> merged = processing.runalg('qgis:mergevectorlayers', [l1, l2], None)
>>> merged['OUTPUT']
u'C:\\Users\\Jochen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\processing30eee19448ef42a497403dd3660cafcf\\82e112158f194f59a53e18d5020a9a9d\\OUTPUT.shp'
```

successfully.

So passing `<ParameterMultipleInput>` as a python list is a solution to this.