# qgis:mergevectorlayers won't allow two layers for the second arg

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, vector, merge

I've been searching the web with no luck. This old exchange should be exactly what I need: [Merging vector layers via python in QGIS 2.18.1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223543/merging-vector-layers-via-python-in-qgis-2-18-1?newreg=7f79812b272c416c8b8f18a8ba23b7e2)

My code looks like this:

```
processing.tools.general.runalg("qgis:mergevectorlayers", importLayer + ";" + masterLayer, tempLayer)
```

But it gives the following error on execution:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'QgsVectorLayer' and 'str' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/visitor/.qgis2/python/plugins\DataImporter\ImporterMain.py", line 47, in run self.dialog.run(layer)
File "C:/Users/visitor/.qgis2/python/plugins\DataImporter\ImporterUIFunctions.py", line 66, in run
self.mergeLayersIntoTemp(layer, layer.masterLayer)
File "C:/Users/visitor/.qgis2/python/plugins\DataImporter\ImporterUIFunctions.py", line 141, in mergeLayersIntoTemp
processing.tools.general.runalg("qgis:mergevectorlayers", importLayer + ";" + masterLayer, tempLayer)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'QgsVectorLayer' and 'str'
```

Both importLayer and masterLayer are QgsVectorLayer objects, so I can only conclude it dislikes adding the ; in this fashion.

How is one supposed to send the layers to be merged these days?

EDIT:

The full code

```
def mergeLayersIntoTemp(self, importLayer, masterName):
    masterLayer = Utils.getLayerByName(masterName)
    tempLayerName = masterName + "_temp"

    tempLayer = ""
    provider = ""
    if not Utils.getLayerByName(tempLayerName):
        tempLayer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=epsg:4326&index=yes", tempLayerName, "memory")
        provider = tempLayer.dataProvider()
    else: # We already have a temp player of this name. Something's wrong.
        ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, u"Attempted to create duplicate temporary layer.", u"Error", 0x0|0x10)
        return

    tempLayer.startEditing()

    #for field in masterLayer.pendingFields():
        #name = field.name()
        #fieldType = field.typeName()
        #provider.addAttributes([QgsField(name, getattr(QVariant, fieldType))])

    tempLayer.commitChanges()
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(tempLayer)


    Processing.initialize()
    processing.tools.general.runalg("qgis:mergevectorlayers", [importLayer, masterLayer], tempLayer)

def getLayerByName(name):
    layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(name)
    if layers:
        return layers[0]
```

importLayer is passed through from the top, it's the layer selected when the tool is run. This is a plugin, not console.

Comment: Layers must be separated by '+' characters.

Comment: Can you specify which QGIS version you are using please?

Comment: I use QGIS 2.18.11.

Answer (score 2):

I think the more recent QGIS versions require putting your layers into a list (i.e. `[importLayer,masterLayer]`). So you could try:

```
processing.tools.general.runalg("qgis:mergevectorlayers", [importLayer,masterLayer], tempLayer)
```

---

Edit:

The Processing algorithm already creates a temporary layer so there's no need to create one **before** running the algorithm. Instead, you can call the output for this and then modify it and add it to the interface:

```
Processing.initialize()

result = processing.tools.general.runalg("qgis:mergevectorlayers", [importLayer,masterLayer], None)
tempLayer = processing.getObject(result['OUTPUT'])

tempLayer.startEditing()
#for field in masterLayer.pendingFields():
    #name = field.name()
    #fieldType = field.typeName()
    #provider.addAttributes([QgsField(name, getattr(QVariant, fieldType))])

tempLayer.commitChanges()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(tempLayer)
```

---

*Tested on QGIS 2.18.2 for Win7 64-bit.*

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately this leads to a new error:

`'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute '__getitem__' See log for more details`

There is nothing of interest in the log.

Comment: @IceDreamer - Can you please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/251773/edit) your question to include the code snippet you used (i.e. how you defined your layers etc). And are you running this from a standalone script or from the QGIS Python Console?

Comment: Edit made. Hope it helps us get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @Joseph Layers must be separated by '+' characters; not in list.

Comment: @xunilk - There may be a version conflict here. My method works for me using QGIS 2.18.2 whereas your method for QGIS 2.18.11 does not work...

Comment: I use QGIS 2.18.11.

Comment: I am version 2.18.11, code revision 29548e7.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code in my system and it worked:

```
import processing

registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()

polygon1 = registry.mapLayersByName('polygon1')
polygon8 = registry.mapLayersByName('polygon8')

processing.runandload('qgis:mergevectorlayers',
                      polygon1 + polygon8,
                      None)
```

Layers must be separated by '+' characters. This was the successful result:

[image]

**Editing Note:**

This is another alternative version of code that works:

```
import processing

registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()

polygon1 = registry.mapLayersByName('polygon1')
polygon8 = registry.mapLayersByName('polygon8')

processing.runandload('qgis:mergevectorlayers',
                      [polygon1[0]] + [polygon8[0]],
                      None)
```

Comment: No joy. For my current layer definitions I get an unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'QgsVectorLayer' and 'QgsVectorLayer'. If I change it to fetch the master layer by mapLayersByName(name) rather than mapLayersByName()[0], I get the same error between 'QgsVectorLayer' and 'list'. Unsupported operand. 

Python script really, really doesn't like combining the args...

Comment: As said Joseph, it looks like a version conflict here. For me works perfectly.

Comment: Looks like I'm running the same version as you, so that can't be it. 

I am a bit confused how your code works. Because you're not calling the [0] index on the mapLayersByName(), surely your version sent lists of layers, rather than actual layers?

Comment: I closed my QGIS and opened it again to run script. I got same successful result.

Comment: See my **Editing Note**. In that code I'm calling the [0] index on the mapLayersByName() and it works too.

Comment: In that edit, the listing is recursive. polygon1 == [polygon1[0]]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63663/discussion-between-icedreamer-and-xunilk).

Answer (score 1):

The hint was in xunilk not fetching his layers, but an index containing each layer.

The successful syntax appears to be:

```
processing.tools.general.runalg("qgis:mergevectorlayers", [list1] + [list2], destination)
```

Lists. Not layers. This needs documenting somewhere...

As a side note, while my code now completes with no errors, using None as the final output, I don't get a "Merged" layer output like xunilk did. What is supposed to happen with that flag?

Comment: Because I'm using 'runandload' method (it loads layer automatically). With 'runalg' doesn't.